# React Native | Firebase authentication | Impossible to trigger navigator

Tags: authentication, firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication

I’ve been stuck since 3 days with this problem. I’ve recently migrated my app to Firebase and React Native everything is working like a charm except for the user Authentication. I’m trying to trigger my navigator when the user logs in. So I’m using the following method :

```
componentDidMount() {
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
     if (user) {
        global.userID = user.uid
        alert(‘test’)        

        var naviRef = this.refs.NavRef
        naviRef.push({
          ident: ‘Home’
        })
    } else {
      // No user is signed in.
    }
 });
}
```

I get the alert(‘test’) but my navigator does nothing. If I put the naviRef.push outside the « onAuthStateChanged » it is working. I have no idea what I can do now. Is there a better solution than using a navigator ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this should do the trick:

```js
componentDidMount() {
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
     if (user) {
        global.userID = user.uid
        alert(‘test’)        

        var naviRef = this.refs.NavRef
        naviRef.push({
          ident: ‘Home’
        })
    } else {
      // No user is signed in.
    }
 });
}
```

Now the `this` inside the function is correct as arrow function does lexical binding of this. Hence, you can properly access the `this.refs.NavRef`

Comment: Solved my problem ! Thank you